# How to style font size of event text in RadCalendar Day Cell

Tags: android, nativescript, svelte, svelte-component

I am using nativescript [radCalendar](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/Calendar/Styling/month-view) component in my svelte native application. I am unable to update Font size of the Event displayed in day cell. I am able to update font size of date but event text has no effect. Testing  device is pixel1 with android10.

my function to build month view

```
function buildMonthView() {
        const monthViewStyle = new CalendarMonthViewStyle();

        const dayCellStyle = new DayCellStyle();
        dayCellStyle.showEventsText = true;
        dayCellStyle.eventTextSize = 30;
        dayCellStyle.eventFontStyle = CalendarFontStyle.Bold;
        dayCellStyle.cellTextSize = 14;
        monthViewStyle.dayCellStyle = dayCellStyle;

        return monthViewStyle;
    }
```

**Edit:**
Playground link: [Example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=DKSI1b&v=191)

Comment: How you are assigning monthViewStyle on the calendar? Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: playground link added in question

Comment: Are you sure you have shared right Playground sample, because you said it's Svelte but the Playground is built with Angular.

Comment: This playground is build by someone else who faced same issue using angular but it was asked on different forum and still open.
This component has same behavior in svelte native also

Comment: Wait until loaded event of calendar, then try setting the font size - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=DKSI1b&v=275

Comment: no effect, tested this on pixel1 from your provided playground and event text is still of same size. `dayCellStyle.eventTextSize = 20;` this line has no effect

Comment: @Manoj found any solution or workaround?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why it doesn't work, it's hard to debug as its closed source. Try this - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=DKSI1b&v=276

Comment: Perfect! this solution worked for me. Could you please post this solution as answer so I can mark it correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the text size natively in loaded event of calendar

```
  // Android only
  if (event.object.nativeView.getEventAdapter()) {
    event.object.nativeView.getEventAdapter().getRenderer().setEventTextSize(20 * utilsModule.layout.getDisplayDensity());
  }
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=DKSI1b&v=276)